# How to prove Average height of Binary Search Tree is O(logn)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I had thought of a proof but unable to sketch things up on paper.
I had though of the Recurrence relation for the height of a binary search tree would be

> T(n)=T(k)+T(n-k-1)+1

Where k is the Number of elements in the left subtree if root and n-k-1 are on right subtree of root (and n= total nodes)

(Correct me if the thing above is wrong)

Now what I thought, because we have to calculate for average case..
So there would be half of the cases possible...
(Now this is the point from where I am starting messing up things plz correct here..)

My claim: I would have approx half cases out of all possible..
Example

Root

> (0,N-1) OR
>   (1, N-2) OR
>   . 
>   . 
>   (N-1,0)

Where N is total nodes.
Now I am considering half of above cases for average case calculation...
(I don't know whether I am doing this right or not..comment on it would be most appreciated)

So I get :

T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/2)+1

> T(n)=2T(n/2)+1

Now when I apply master method for getting approx answer over the obtained recurrence relation..
I get O(n).

Now how should I proceed...?
(My expectation was instead of n I should have got logn)
But that didn't work out..
So plz suggest how should I proceed further.
(Is my approach even at all correct..from start, also tell me about that?)

Comment: Your recurrence for the height of the tree is incorrect. Currently, it is counting the number of nodes rather than the height. The recurrence for the expectation you probably want is something of the form $T(n) = \frac1n \sum_k (1+\max{T(k), T(n-k-1)})$, if you assume a uniform distribution. I believe you can show by induction that $T(n) = O(\log n)$. Use the fact that $\log(n!) \leq n\log n$ (why?).

Comment: Don't forget that this is only true for perfectly balanced trees. Less balanced trees will have longer heights. Consider a BST that only has left nodes. Then you essentially have a linked list where the height == number of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "Algorithms" by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne

> Definition. A binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where each node has a
>   Comparable key (and an associated value) and satisfies the restriction that the key
>   in any node is larger than the keys in all nodes in that node’s left subtree and smaller than the keys in all nodes in that node’s right subtree.

**Proposition C.** Search hits in a BST built from N random keys require ~ 2 ln N
(about 1.39 lg N) compares, on the average.

**Proof:** The number of compares used for a search hit ending at a given node is
1 plus the depth. Adding the depths of all nodes, we get a quantity known as the
internal path length of the tree. Thus, the desired quantity is 1 plus the average internal path length of the BST, which we can analyze with the same argument that
we used for Proposition K in Section 2.3: Let CN be the total internal path length
of a BST built from inserting N randomly ordered distinct keys, so that the average
cost of a search hit is 1 CN / N. We have C0= C1= 0 and for N > 1 we can write a
recurrence relationship that directly mirrors the recursive BST structure:

*CN = N  1  (C0  CN1) / N + (C1  CN2)/N  . . . (CN1  C0 )/N*

The N  1 term takes into account that the root contributes 1 to the path length
of each of the other N  1 nodes in the tree; the rest of the expression accounts
for the subtrees, which are equally likely to be any of the N sizes. After rearranging
terms, this recurrence is nearly identical to the one that we solved in Section 2.3
for quicksort, and we can derive the approximation CN ~ 2N ln N

I also reccommend you to check this Mit lecture [Binary Search Trees, BST Sort](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jry5-82I68&t=2071s)

Also check the chapter 3.2 from Algorithms books, it explains binary search trees in depth

Comment: Okay thanks it was intuitive...(sorry I reacted late)